# AspectJ doesn't work properly when using Java and Kotlin together

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

I'm using AspectJ with Kotlin and JavaScript.

My pointcut is a method in a Java class, but AspectJ runs weave in task `compileKotlin`. Because of this, AspectJ seems can't access the Java class before `compileJava` was executed.

The error:

```
> Task :compileKotlin

2 warnings
cc\nostaldaisuki\aspectjtest\AspectJTest.kt [warning] no match for this type name: cc.nostaldaisuki.aspectjtest.Class1 [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    
G:\Codes\JVM\aspectj-test\build\classes\kotlin\main!cc\nostaldaisuki\aspectjtest\AspectJTest.class [warning] advice defined in cc.nostaldaisuki.aspectjtest.AspectJTest has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
    

> Task :compileJava
```

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.22"
    id("io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving") version "8.4"
    id("java")
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.8.RC3")
    implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.8.RC3")
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

My test project:

[image: IDE project folder structure]

My application entry:

```kotlin
package cc.nostaldaisuki.aspectjtest

fun main() {
    val class1Instance = Class1("Hello!")
    class1Instance.sayHello()
}
```

The class which contains AspectJ statement:

```kotlin
package cc.nostaldaisuki.aspectjtest

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect

@Aspect
class AspectJTest {
    @Around("execution(* cc.nostaldaisuki.aspectjtest.Class1.sayHello())")
    fun replaceSayHello(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint) {
        val targetObject = joinPoint.target as Class1Kt
        val field = targetObject.javaClass.getDeclaredField("content")
        field.isAccessible = true
        val fieldContent = field.get(targetObject) as String
        Class2.replacement(fieldContent)
    }
}
```

I tried to rewrite `Class1` in Kotlin (Which is `Class1Kt` in the picture above) and do the same thing, It just works well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Some code is missing, the aspect code does not fit the Java target class, and all volunteers here have to fill in the gaps. Please improve the question by adding a link to a GitHub project with the full reproducer.

Answer (score 0):

In Gradle, it is not as easy as in Maven to configure which compilation steps in a build should happen in which order.

By default, Groovy compilation depends on Java compilation depends on Kotlin compilation, see [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/kotlin-groovy-and-java-compilation/14903/8). I.e., Java compilation always happens after Kotlin. That could lead to problems, if the Kotlin aspect is compiled and woven first.

But I found out that a Java aspect is also only applied to Java code. The Freefair plugin seems to be implemented in an inflexible way.

My suggestion is to have one module for Java and Kotlin compilation and another one for post-compile aspect weaving, putting the first module on the inpath. That way, the build steps are clearly ordered and not all mixed up in a single module, making the situation hard to control.

Sorry for not being more specific, but Gradle is not my strong suit, I am a Maven guy. But I do know AspectJ.